# Easy way to get process information from a window

Tags: 18.04, window, process

On Windows, I can use Process Explorer and drag its crosshairs to a window, then Process Explorer highlights the associated process.

On Ubuntu, I didn't find such a function in System Monitor. What's the easy way to get process from window?

I'm open to downloading an alternative process monitor or other tools.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you can use Terminal, try this:

```
xprop | grep WM_CLASS
```

and your cursor should turn into cross allowing you to click on any window to get its process name. If you just need the PID, try:

```
xprop | awk '/PID/ {print $3}'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `grep` is not really necessary, you can give a property name as argument to show only that one, like `xprop WM_CLASS` directly. Note that especially the `WM_CLASS` does not have to be the same as the process executable, it can be an arbitrary value as set by the developer.

Answer (score 15):

Using `xprop` is already mentioned [in this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1162515/367990) and probably the best solution.

Another way might be to use `wmctrl -lp` to list all windows managed by your window manager together with their respective process IDs (PID) where possible:

```bsh
$ wmctrl -lp
0x03a00002  0 1570   type40mark3 XdndCollectionWindowImp
0x03a00003  0 1570   type40mark3 unity-launcher
0x03a00004  0 1570   type40mark3 unity-panel
0x03a00005  0 1570   type40mark3 unity-dash
0x03a00006  0 1570   type40mark3 Hud
0x02c0000a -1 302    type40mark3 Desktop
0x08a00003  0 8861   type40mark3 18.04 - Easy way to get process from window - Ask Ubuntu - Mozilla Firefox
0x08a00033  0 8861   type40mark3 Some other site in a different window - Mozilla Firefox
0x0840b72c  0 20705  type40mark3 bytecommander@type40mark3: ~
0x08800001  0 7389   type40mark3 New Tab - Chromium
```

You could then use this PID to get more info about the process, e.g. with `ps aux -q YOUR_PID_HERE`:

```bsh
$ ps aux -q 20705
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
bytecom+ 20705  0.0  0.2 676820 32268 ?        Sl   Jun28   1:58 /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this command. I more like the other visual way. Sometimes a window doesn't have title bar or is boradless, I can't really tell from this list given by wmctrl.